# Incorrect comments set for php in vim

Tags: php, vim

My vim used to auto-continue comments in php. For example:

```
/* |  <- cursor here
```

Then, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives me:

```
/*
 * |  <- cursor here
```

and again, gives me:

```
/*
 *
 * |  <- cursor here
```

etc...

As far as I understand it, this is controlled by the `comments` and `formatoptions` options. However, whenever I open a php file now, `comments` is set to:

`s:<!--,m:    ,e:-->`

I've looked all over my ~/.vim folder, as well as the $VIMRUNTIME folder, and I can't find out where/why this changed, and why the `comments` option is being set incorrectly.

Here's a link to my .vimrc

http://pastebin.com/f1509ce65

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the default settiings of version 7.3 (patchset 754), I observe the same bug as in your original post:

```
/**<ENTER>
```

Expected result:

```
/**
 * <cursor>
```

Actual result:

```
/**
<cursor>
```

The solution consists of two steps:

- Add a command that makes vim detect comments (see [Issue 75 for vim on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=75))
- Add a command that makes vim automatically insert comment continuations (apply the reverse of [Vim: can I disable continuation of comments to the next line?](https://superuser.com/a/271024/47108))

The modification to my vimrc that takes these two steps into account:

```
au FileType php setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,:#
au FileType php setlocal formatoptions+=cro
```

Hurrah!

Comment: As you say *"With the default settings"* it might not be the case, but sure it is not due to wrong order of *indent* and *plugin*? Ref. my own answer.

Answer (score 8):

#### Note.

Note that this issue can also arise if one have *filetype* `indent on` and `plugin on` at separate lines in *.vimrc*:

```
filetype indent on
filetype plugin on
```

This causes `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/php.vim` to be processed before `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/php.vim`.

The *`indent/php.vim`* file resets `'comments'`, but *`ftplugin/php.vim`* does not.

---

#### Order of mess:

*`indent/php.vim`* get sourced and `comments` correctly set:

```
setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,:#
```

Then *`ftplugin/php.vim`* get sourced. It again sources *`ftplugin/html.vim`* by:

```
runtime! ftplugin/html.vim ftplugin/html_*.vim ftplugin/html/*.vim
```

which result in *`ftplugin/html.vim`* being processed and setting:

```
setlocal commentstring=<!--%s-->
setlocal comments=s:<!--,m:\ \ \ \ ,e:-->
```

Later on in *`ftplugin/php.vim`* the `commentstring` is *reset* but not `comments`:

```
setlocal commentstring=/*%s*/
```

---

#### Fix:

```vim
filetype indent plugin on

" Or
filetype plugin indent on

" Or with correct order:
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

---

#### PS.

In any case plugin should be processed before indent.

To check order of inclusion/processing have a look at `:scriptnames`.

Comment: Although Lekensteyn offers a workaround that should patch the issue, this response seems to identify the underlying cause. When I make a single line in vimrc with `filetype plugin indent on`, then my comments value is correct when I load a PHP buffer without having to hijack the comments value manually.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I had a funky .vim/indent/php.vim file that somehow was screwing it up.

Deleted it, and the functionality I was looking for returned. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

The `php.vim` file should be in your `ftplugin` folder in `$VIMRUNTIME`.

In version 7.2 of vim, the comments line is line 74 in that file.

Did that file get deleted or moved?

Comment: No, it's still there.
Maintainer: Dan Sharp
URL: http://dwsharp.users.sourceforge.net/vim/ftplugin

Comment: do you have any files in your personal .vim/ftplugin that could be overriding the comments? Or your .vim/filetype.vim for that matter?